# spring boot serve angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Im having trouble serving my angular application with Spring boot.

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "index";
}
```

Folder structure

```
resources > public > index.html
```

If I go to localhost:8080/home I get this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 17 13:30:33 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

But if I go directly to http://localhost:8080/index.html it does work

If I go straight to http://localhost:8080 I get:

```
No mapping for GET /
```

Answer (score 0):

Files you place under resources/public are for static hosted files - this is where you would place html landing pages, css, images and JS resources - no request mapping is needed in code.

Your code example should only return the string defined but without seeing the rest of the code its hard to say why its failing.

Comment: What extra information do you need to help me figure this out?

Comment: I fixed it. I had a second config file annotated with @EnableWebMvc. It started working after I removed this.